# Which answer should I choose?

Tags: discussion

I'm kind of a new user to sci-fi stackexchange when it comes to asking questions and choosing a best answer.

Yesterday I asked the question "[Movie in which person turns into monster by mask with tubes](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/57284/24993)" (the wording could be better, but nevermind).
There are two answers suggesting the same movie (which is the one I was looking for), posted 3 minutes from eachother. They both have a youtube video with the concerning scene (one a bit shorter than the other).
Also, they both have the same amount of votes.

I know I should choose the answer that best answers my question, but I just can't choose.
Which answer would you choose and why?
Or should I wait first to see if other answers come in?

Comment: Dupe(ish); http://meta.scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/3615/i-cant-decide-which-answer-to-choose-what-do-i-do

Comment: You go and upvote any one, they will have different votes then... If you have already voted both, undo your vote on any one, if you have passed the vote removal time limit, make a minor edit, so that it gets accepted, then remove your vote! so many options sitting around, see :)

Comment: (question timeline here: [Timeline](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/posts/57284/timeline))

Comment: Post a bounty asking for improved details.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Personally I'd choose Mario's answer. Although the answers were almost identically timed and almost identically worded, the video link he offers seems to be from a higher quality source.

By comparison, calccrypto's video seems to be some sort of jerky screen capture.

Ultimately, you're entitled to use **whatever criteria you want** to make an "accepted" response. The specific quote from the [help centre FAQ](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/help/accepted-answer) is:

> *Accepting an answer is not meant to be a definitive and final statement indicating that the question has now been answered
>   perfectly. It simply means that the author received an answer that
>   worked for him or her personally, but not every user comes back to
>   accept an answer, and of those who do, they may not change the
>   accepted answer if a newer, better answer comes along later.*

Comment: @nidunc - I like the fact that you've marked this as accepted, then completely ignored my suggestion... :-)

Comment: They didn't have the same amount of votes anymore, and "Ultimately, you're entitled to use whatever criteria you want to make an "accepted" response." ;)

Comment: Maybe you should have asked a question on meta.meta.scifi.stackechange.com on which answer to accept here? ;)

Comment: @tobiasvl - Then it's turtles all the way down...

Comment: @tobiasvl Good idea, and then ask a question on which answer to accept on that question, and so on. An endless chain of questions

Comment: @Richard calccrypto's video wasn't really jerky, but it was a screen capture. While I do agree that Mario's video is higher quality, calccrypto's video included a longer part of the movie, like the little bit where he is strapped to the 'bed' - whatever you call it - before he gets the serum inserted.

Answer (score 0):

Where people have provided the same correct answer in what is likely to be an overlapping post scenario, I would generally prefer to accept the first answer posted, even if the difference in time is quite short.

Comment: It's a tricky one with story-ident questions. There's a inherent desire to reward the first poster, even when it's only a few seconds difference